# use the correct number of arguments for new in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am working on a gem that can uses different version of Gherkin, but I'm facing a problem:
in the 2.4.0 version Gherkin::Formatter::Model::Scenario.new takes 6 arguments but in 2.6.5 it takes 7 arguments.

So my question is what is a best practice in this case ? Should I do:

```
case Gherkin::Version
when '2.4.0'
  do the init with 6 arguments
else
  with the 7 
end
```

I was thinking also of creating a new_with_arity method:

```
class Object
  def new_with_arity(*params)
    puts method(:initialize).arity # => -1
    puts method(:new).arity        # => -1
    new(*(params + [nil] * (params.count - method(:new).arity)))
  end
end
```

However this does not work, the arity of new and initialize is -1.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend following Jim Deville's advice. Saying that it's quite an interesting idea and you were pretty close. The problem is you can't get the method without having an instance, so the trick is to use allocate first.

```
class Object
  def new_with_arity(*params)
    new *(params + [nil] * (allocate.method(:initialize).arity - params.size))
  end
end


class One
  def initialize a
    [a]
  end
end

class Two
  def initialize a, b
    [a, b]
  end
end

One.new_with_arity 1     #=> [1]
Two.new_with_arity 1, 2  #=> [1, 2]
Two.new_with_arity 1     #=> [1, nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would build 2 Gherkin adapters and load up the proper one for the proper version. Or, you are using Rubygems, so you can force a specific version of the Gherkin parser